# how to remove null bytes generated at 3rd line in terminal (add [eax],al)?

Tags: assembly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPdnQ.png)

left side - Sublime text editor.
right side - Terminal.

Comment: Seriously, image of code instead of code as text...

Comment: seriously, every single of your questions has *not enough background*. You've been told that you need to give context already. So, I'm not sorry to vote to close this as too broad, because you basically ask us how to assembler without even trying to narrow down your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is being assembled as 16-bit code and you are disassembling it as 32-bit code.